# disappeared toggle box on jquery 1.10 version

Tags: jquery, toggle

I just made a jquery toggle using jquery 1.10, it disappeared.

But it works fine on jquery 1.6 version.

what do i need to fix the the problem  ?

http://jsfiddle.net/5Wu6m/261/

```
$(".login").toggle(function() {
    $(this).animate({left: '20'},80);
    $(this).removeClass('on');
    $('.tab2').show('');
    $('.tab1').hide('');

}, function() {
    $(this).animate({left: '0'},80);
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $('.tab1').show(''); 
    $('.tab2').hide(''); 
});
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't provided too much info on what exactly you would like to achieve, I'm going to give you an example on how you can use `toggle` re-using some of what you originally posted in your fiddle:

```
$(".login").click(function () {
    $('.tab1, .tab2').toggle(function () {
    });
});
```

Your new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Wu6m/262/

The display or hide is already happening by just using the toggle function, and anything you add inside is going to be what's going to be triggered at the end of the animation.

It takes 2 arguments, but not 2 different functions, instead just the duration and a function of completion.

More info can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/